# How Can I Clear Selection of NSComboBox in Swift or Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, macos, nscombobox

We can clear the selection of ComboBox coding this:

```
combobox.SelectedIndex=-1;
```

with C# on Windows. 
However, it this coding methodology cannot run for macOS and iOS NSComboBox with Swift or Objective - C. What is the real solution ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in the documentation. `NSComboBox` has a method:

```
func deselectItem(at index: Int)
```

and to get the index of the selected item:

```
var indexOfSelectedItem: Int { get }
```

Comment: Yes. I tried it also. However, deselect(indexOfSelectedItem) cannot run for me.

Comment: @Berk B. This is the right solution, try to make a new project.

Comment: Which code did you try? And which error message was shown?